# How to toggle box when web scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the site https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2021/rushing.htm#, and I am trying to sort by the column `Y/A`.

#### Code

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = f'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2021/rushing.htm'
html = urlopen(url)
stats_page = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")

rows = [[i.getText() for i in row.findAll('td')] for row in stats_page.findAll('tr')[1:]]
for row in rows:
    if len(row) == 0: rows.remove(row)
rows.sort(key=lambda x: float(x[11]), reverse=True)
```

###### Output

`[['C.J. Moore', 'DET', '26', '', '8', '0', '1', '28', '0', '1', '28', '28.0', '3.5', '0'], ['Diontae Johnson', 'PIT', '25', 'wr', '6', '6', '1', '25', '0', '1', '25', '25.0', '4.2', '0'], ['Marcus Mariota', 'LVR', '28', '', '2', '0', '2', '35', '0', '1', '31', '17.5', '17.5', '0']...`

#### Problem

While this does technically return what I asked for, I wanted something different. I realized that when I go to the website I see this toggle: [image]

There is a toggle that says "When table is sorted, hide non-qualifiers". When that is toggled, the output should look something more like `[[Lamar Jackson, BAL, 24, qb, 7, 7, 76, 480, 2, 29, 31, 6.3, 68.6, 5], [Jalen Hurts, PHI, 23, qb 8, 8, 73, 432, 5, 29, 27, 5.9, 54.0, 5]...]`. But when it's not toggled, it looks like the output I posted above.

However, when you scrape the website it defaults to off. Is there a way to toggle this to be on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could target the table by id, then exclude rows where there are `tds` having a class of `non_qual`. I would use the html from these rows, wrapped with `table` tags, to reconstitute the table with pandas. Finally, sort and tidy the table.

Given there appear to be some ties, within `Y/A`, it looks like there is a secondary sort on `Att` desc e.g. page output the following order for Y/A 4.5 (current 2021-11-07)

```
18  Aaron Jones 
19  Dalvin Cook 
20  Melvin Gordon   
21  David Montgomery
```

---

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get(
    'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2021/rushing.htm')

soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

t = pd.read_html('<table>' + ''.join([str(r) for r in soup.select(
    '#rushing tr:not(:has(td.non_qual))')]) + '</table>')[0]

t.columns = [i[1] for i in t.columns]
t = t[t.Rk != 'Rk'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore")
t.sort_values(['Y/A', 'Att'], ascending=[False, False], inplace=True)
t.Rk = [i+1 for i in range(len(t.index))]
t.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

t
```

---

**Sample output:**

[image]